# Dockerizing play framework

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, dockerfile, playframework-2.6

My docker compose file is:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: crm-psql
    image: postgres:9.3
    restart: always
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_DB=crm
    - POSTGRES_USER=root
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
    - ./db/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  nginx:
    container_name: crm-nginx
    image: nginx:1.15
    restart: always
    ports:
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
    volumes:
    - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
    - 9000:9000
    volumes:
    - .:/src/main/java
    - ~/.ivy2:/root/.ivy2
    - ~/.sbt:/root/.sbt
    links:
    - postgres
    - nginx
```

The docker file for build is:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk
ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin

ENV SBT_VERSION 1.2.1

# Install curl
RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y install curl && \
  apt-get -y install vim

# Install sbt
RUN \
  curl -L -o sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  dpkg -i sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  rm sbt-$SBT_VERSION.deb && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get -y install sbt

WORKDIR /src/main/java
COPY . /src/main/java
RUN sbt update
EXPOSE 9000
ENTRYPOINT ["sbt", "run"]
```

Whenever I do docker-compose up, the connection doesn't gets established to postgres. The exception is

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

However when i exec in container crm-psql and type psql crm, it goes into postgres shell. What is the issue here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you use localhost to indicate your database. You should use your link instead. From the point of view of your "sbt" container, localhost is itself and not your local machine (with the port forwarding) or your postgresql container.

Generaly what I use is environment variables.

```
links:
  - postgres
  - nginx
environment: 
  - POSTGRES_SERVICE_HOST=postgres
```

After you need to specify in your SBT script how to use your POSTGRES_SERVICE_HOST variable

Comment: Made the change. Also when I do docker compose up, everything starts perfectly and then the akka server stops. Here are the logs for the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53258307/akka-server-automatically-stops

Can you answer this as well? Looks like the enter command is being passed to terminal through docker

Comment: Unfortunately, I  have no idea of your other problem. I have never used SBT. Maybe, you can put additional information about your build.